# whereExact filtering

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I try to get all product from the database and also filter that base on the `request parameters`
so i create some `Models` like `Product`, `Property`, `Attribute`. and create the `many to many` relations between `Product and Property` , `Product and Attribute`.

this is a part of my query:

```
$products = Product::where('status', 'accept')

        ->when(request('properties'), function ($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('id', request('properties'));
        })
        ->when(request('attributes'), function ($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('id', request('attributes'));
        })->get();
```

so there are no errors in here, but what i want here to change is the attributes filtering idea.

i want to change `whereIn` filtering to `whereExact` filtering. thats meen where i send the `request('attributes')` by the value of `[1,2]` to the this query, i expect the result should be :

> All Product  that have attribute by id=1 AND attribute by id=2

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `foreach` with `whereHas()`:

```
$products = Product::where('status', 'accept')
    ->when(request('properties'), function ($query) {
        foreach(request('properties') as $id){
            $query->whereHas('properties', function($query) use ($id){
                $query->where('id', $id);
            });
        }
    })
    ->when(request('attributes'), function ($query) {
        foreach(request('attributes') as $id){
            $query->whereHas('attributes', function($query) use ($id){
                $query->where('id', $id);
            });
        }
    })->get();
```

First argument of `whereHas()` should be the method name of relation.